# Custom re-arrange list using python

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I have the following list:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','I','J', 'K', 'L','M','N','O']
```

I would like to sort the list such that every sixth element comes after the fifth value, eleventh after the second, second after the third, so on. The list should be of the following output:

```
['A', 'F', 'K', 'B', 'G', 'L', 'C', 'H', 'M', 'D', 'I', 'N', 'E', 'J', 'O']
```

What I tried so far?

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','I','J', 'K', 'L','M','N','O']
new_lst = [lst[0], lst[5], lst[10], lst[1], lst[6], lst[11], lst[2], lst[7], lst[12], lst[3], lst[8], lst[13] , lst[4], lst[9], lst[14]]
new_lst
```

This provides the desired output, but I am looking for an optimal script. How do I do that?

Comment: You say "every sixth element comes after the fifth value," but then you want 'F' (the sixth element) way *before* 'E' (the fifth element)? Your description/example makes no sense to me.

Comment: The sixth element should be second element, eleventh element should be third element, so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the pattern, reshape as 2d then transpose and flatten

sum is convenient function where you can mention start point, in this case the identity is () or [], depending on type

```py
### sol 1
import numpy as np
print('Using numpy')
x = ['A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H','I','J', 'K', 'L','M','N','O']
np.array(x).reshape((-1, 5)).transpose().reshape(-1)
# array(['A', 'F', 'K', 'B', 'G', 'L', 'C', 'H', 'M', 'D', 'I', 'N', 'E', 'J', 'O'], dtype='<U1')

# Sol 2
print('One more way without numpy')
list(
    sum(
        zip(x[:6], x[5:11], x[10:]),
        ()
    )
)

# Sol 3
print('One more way without numpy')
sum(
    [list(y) for y in zip(x[:6], x[5:11], x[10:])],
    []
)

# Sol 4
print('One more way without numpy')
list(
    sum(
        [y for y in zip(x[:6], x[5:11], x[10:])],
        ()
    )
)
```

Comment: This gives me a good idea. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sum is very convenient i came to know recently. Before I had misunderstanding that sum can only be used for list with numerical entries

Comment: @DanielHao it can bedone using zip, please look again

Comment: Good solutions, but you should try to make the answer more human readable (seperate different appraoches) and make it easier to copy paste, e.g. remove `>>> `

Answer (score 2):

You can also use list comprehension if you want to avoid libraries:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']

[x for t in zip(lst[:6], lst[5:11], lst[10:]) for x in t]

# ['A', 'F', 'K', 'B', 'G', 'L', 'C', 'H', 'M', 'D', 'I', 'N', 'E', 'J', 'O']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it repeating for every fifth and tenth element after current, then it would be

```py
# Must consist of at least 14 values
input_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']

output_list = []
for i in range(len(t) // 3):
    output_list.append(t[i])
    output_list.append(t[i + 5])
    output_list.append(t[i + 10])

print(output_list)
```

No libraries used. It will give the desired result:

```py
['A', 'F', 'K', 'B', 'G', 'L', 'C', 'H', 'M', 'D', 'I', 'N', 'E', 'J', 'O']
```

Comment: Just have to make sure that **len(t) // 3 + 10** exists.

Comment: Thanks that helps! Here, t is input_list, right?

Comment: @disukumo It is. Check out root163's answer too. There are couple convenient one-liners that use `zip()`.